# Adding sub-view inside an Other subview

Tags: iphone, uialertview, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to add an activity Indicator View inside and Alert Box is it possible to add an subView inside Another subView?

Comment: yes it's possible and for all the objets inherited from UIView.

Comment: Yes it is possible to add sub view inside another subview.  
But i'm not sure you can add an activity indicator inside alert view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code :

```
  UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@" " message:@" " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
        UIActivityIndicatorView *myActivityIndicatorView= [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 60, 40, 40)];
        myActivityIndicatorView.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
        [myAlert addSubview:myActivityIndicatorView];
        [myActivityIndicatorView startAnimating];
        [myAlert show];
```

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible...

[alertView addSubview:activityIndicator];

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes.
Simply alloc and init both views, then call

```
[alertView addSubview:activityView];
```

However, if this passes Apple's inspection is doubtful, so you may not be able to publish to the AppStore.